# facebook shows a blank page with ssl page

Tags: facebook, ssl

I have changed my application to secure page and facebook show a [blank page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9F-%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9E/114903208585578?sk=app_114043768673499)

[This is the link for my secure page](https://outlet.bvd.co.il/zap-fb/file/fbpage_48411335859815.php)

I have attached the application print screen

Please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both the `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL` fields should be a fully qualified URL.

For legacy reasons, the `Page Tab URL` will still accept a path relative to your Canvas URL, but this backwards compatibility isn't in place for the Secure Page Tab URL